# AngularJS - How can I know when a promise on a parent controller has been resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that relies upon data from its parent's controller. This data is returned in a promise. How can I know when the promise, which exists on the parent controller, has been resolved?

Parent Controller

```
angular.module("UserShoes").controller("UserController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.user = User.get({
    userId: 1 
  });

  $scope.shoes = [];

  $scope.user.$promise.then(function (data) {
    data.shoes.forEach(function (shoe, index) {
      if (shoe) {
        $scope.shoes.push(shoe);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Directive

```
angular.module("UserShoes").directive("Shoes", ["", function () {
  return {
    ...

    controller: function ($scope) {
      // When will $scope.parent.shoes be ready? :-(
    }
    ...
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Tip: Anonymous functions for controllers are not helpful for debugging and code cleanliness. See [this talk](https://youtu.be/UlvCbnKAH3g?t=31m50s) by John Papa for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You could broadcast an event and listen for that event in your directive.

From your parent controller:

```
angular.module("UserShoes").controller("UserController", function ($scope) {
      $scope.user = User.get({
        userId: 1 
      });

      $scope.shoes = [];

      $scope.user.$promise.then(function (data) {
        data.shoes.forEach(function (shoe, index) {
          if (shoe) {
            $scope.shoes.push(shoe);
          }
        });
        $scope.$broadcast('shoes-ready',$scope.shoes);
      });
    });
```

From your directive

```
$scope.$on('shoes-ready',function(evt,shoes){ /*process shoes*/})
```

Comment: The first parameter to the `shoes-ready` event handler will be the `event` object, not the array of shoes.

Comment: This will work, but ideally, events should be reserved for genuinely global events on the system, whilst this is a very local concern.

Comment: Hmm, this could get very expensive down the road if he ends up with a lot of nested scopes underneath the UserController. I'm not sure this is the most efficient solution.

Comment: To be fair, the event handling in Angular has got a lot more efficient in recent versions, and it will only really traverse scopes with handlers for that event registered. So it is not as inefficient as it once was.

Comment: Is it OK to just load the values onto my page's main controller and to allow the directive to reference the values there? That takes care of the whole timing aspect of the issue, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Importing the `$promise` into the directive's scope should work well.  Use `&` to import it as a binding expression:

*view:*

```
<div user-shoes shoes-promise="user.$promise" ... ></div>
```

*directive:*

```
angular.module('myModule')
.directive("Shoes", ["", function () {
  return {
    ...
    scope: {
      shoesPromise: '&'
    }
    ...
  }
}])
```

Then, in directive's `link` function, you can do something with the resolved promise:

```
function link(scope) {
  scope.shoesPromise()
    .then(function(){
      ...
    })
    .catch(...)
}
```

Comment: Personally, calling the scope property `shoes` or `shoesPromise` would make more sense to me. `ngModel` implies two-way binding, and this is only one-way. (Which means you're probably better off using `&` instead of `=` since you don't need two way binding).

Comment: If you use the `&` though, you will need to call it as a method on the scope: `scope.shoesPromise().then(...`

Comment: Is it OK to just load the values onto my page's main controller and to allow the directive to reference the values there? That takes care of the whole timing aspect of the issue, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a $broadcast, which could theoretically become expensive down the road, I would use a $watch and a flag in your controller. Something like:

```
angular.module("UserShoes").controller("UserController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.user = User.get({
    userId: 1 
  });

  $scope.shoes = [];

  $scope.user.$promise.then(function (data) {
    data.shoes.forEach(function (shoe, index) {
      if (shoe) {
        $scope.shoes.push(shoe);
      }
    });
    $scope.shoes_ready = true;
  });
});
```

then in your directive:

```
var stop_watch = scope.$watch('shoes_ready', function(new_value) {
  if (new_value === true) {
    // do work son
    stop_watch();  // Optional, if you are done with this watcher
  }
});
```

Comment: I would not say it is optional to deregister the watch, you should always be aiming to remove watchers once you are done with them. You also don't need to clutter the scope with the watch deregistration function, it only needs to be a local variable.

Comment: Ah, that's right about the local var. But I would say it's optional only because he may not be done with it. Let's say he's making some kind of scroller, and this directive controls infinite scroll. Makes sense to leave it registered because he will load more shoes eventually. But I have no idea what his app does or how this directive is used.

Comment: That sounds like a case of [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) to me. The `shoes_ready` variable is a boolean, and a promise can't be resolved more than once, so it will only ever go from `false` to `true` once. You could even use the new `:: shoes_ready` bind-once syntax to avoid the need to deregister the watcher yourself perhaps.

Comment: Is it OK to just load the values onto my page's main controller and to allow the directive to reference the values there? That takes care of the whole timing aspect of the issue, I think.

Comment: By values do you mean `$scope.shoes`? If so, then yes, that would be the preferred way to do it. It is already available to the scope of the directive, so long as it's not isolate.